# How to draw icons in flutter with custom icon font file?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have custom font icon file named myicons.ttf and myJsonValue.json file with all values defined in it. How to implement icons with these in flutter? I have defined properly in the pubspec.yaml.

```
flutter:
fonts:
- family: icons
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/myicons.ttf

assets:
  - res/myJsonValue.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const myIcon = const IconData('\u1234', fontFamily: 'icons');
```

then use it like

```
const Icon(myIcon);
```

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c97fc2063f7b5b1a3a9bdb937205a237e13246a2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icons.dart#L29 how to create a set of icon data (one for each icon)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its work my app

```
Icon(
                  IconData(0xE905,fontFamily: 'DCB',),color: Colors.green,
                  size: 50,
                )
```

0x is constant and E905 is ttf file icon code